# Google Source Repository out of sync with GitHub

Tags: github, gcloud, google-container-registry

I'm using gcloud's 'Source Repository' to link to a GitHub repo to trigger automated container builds. Unfortunately the Source Code shown in gcloud seems to get out of sync with the GitHub Repo. The example below shows that gcloud is missing the last 7 commits.

[image: GCloud]

[image: GitHub]

This seems to be fixed by removing the code from Google 'Source Repository' and relinking to GitHub but this is a major annoyance. This has happened several times to several different repos over the past couple of months.

Any idea what is causing this and if there is any fix?

Comment: Is this still affecting you? I believe there was an outage last week that may have caused this, but it's since been fixed and affected repos were re-synced.

Comment: Yep, it re-synced itself after a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this issue today, anyone else experiencing this?  There's no service status for cloud repos or github sync so hard to tell, but all my repositories stay in a constant state of "Syncing"

Comment: there was an outage reported about the Cloud Build at the beginning of June, in which builds fail to be triggered. This issue was confirmed to have been fixed. Affected repros were re-synced. However, if the issue is still affecting you, You can follow the steps provided by MrBlenny; removing the code from Google 'Source Repository' and relinking to GitHub